# Sync Outlook calendar with a POP3 account (not Gmail or Hotmail)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to sync my Outlook 2010 calendar with a POP3 account (not Gmail or Hotmail). I usually have meetings with clients on hosted POP3 emails so would like to share my calendar with them.

Is there a way round it?

Answer (score 1):

You can send out event invitations in the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) format as an attachment to normal e-mail, much like Gmail does it. This will allow the recipient to add the event to his/her local calendar. Microsoft has a [help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-an-add-to-calendar-link-in-an-email-message-HA102114161.aspx) that details the steps.

If you wish to share your complete calendar, you will have to set up a calendar somewhere on the internet (for example Gmail) and sync it with your local calendar. You can then share the link to it with your associates, who can - if they want - sync your calendar to their local one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately pop only handles emails not calendars.
Fortunately there are several way to [Share an Outlook calendar with other people](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-HA010354420.aspx#_Toc300732657).

The best for you is probably to share a calendar by publishing it online. Here are the relevant bits from the page linked above (bold by me):

> You can publish your default Outlook 2010 Calendar to the Internet, which enables more people to view it. **Publishing an Internet Calendar requires neither the publisher nor the user to use an Exchange account**.
>
> If you [publish a calendar on Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/redir/HA010355570.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010354420), you can control who can access your calendar on Office.com. You are the only person who can change your calendar, and you can only do so through Outlook. In your default calendar, on the Home tab, in the Share group, click Publish Online, and then click Publish to Office.com.
>
> If you have access to a web server that supports the World Wide Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) protocol, you can choose to publish calendars to that server instead. However, publishing to Office.com provides improved control over who can access your calendar. In your default calendar, on the Home tab, in the Share group, click Publish Online, and then click Publish to WebDAV Server. For more information, see Publish your calendar on a WebDAV server.